# C# - Delete Folder

Tags: c#, winapi, io

I want delete java folder with C#,
but I have little problem.

this is the code

```
private void setDebug(string value)
{
    debug.Text = value;
}

private void buildButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // delete java folder
    string java_folder = @"C:\Program Files\Java";
    if (Directory.Exists(java_folder))
    {
        setDebug("Deleting Java folder...");
        Directory.Delete(java_folder, true);
        progressBar.Value += 10;
    }
}
```

when I click on the button the program stuck, but when i delete the line Directory.Delete
it change the debug label to "Deleting java folder..."

I know that the program stuck because it delete the folder but i want it change the debug first before it delete the folder.

what to do? thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason that your code doesn't appear to be working is because of the way WinForms handles UI updates.

The UI will not repaint until your method `buildButton_Click` completes - and nor will the UI be responsive until that time.  The `Directory.Delete` line is something that will take a long time to run, and so your program "sticks" and you don't see the debug label.

What you need to do is look into using threading - read up on Threads, Tasks or the BackgroundWorker class in order to understand how they work.  Then, instead of calling `Directory.Delete` directly in your method, use one of those techniques to run the delete on a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code in a different thread, like this:

```
private void setDebug(string value)
{
    debug.Text = value;
}

private void buildButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    string java_folder = @"C:\Program Files\Java";
    if (Directory.Exists(java_folder))
    {
        setDebug("Deleting Java folder...");
        worker.DoWork += (s, args) => // this is the off-thread code
        {
            // delete java folder
            Directory.Delete(java_folder, true);
        };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s,args)=>  // this goes off when .DoWork is done
        {
            progressBar.Value += 10; 
        };

        // this invokes .DoWork handler (which we defined above)
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark it as accepted if it solved your issue, so future visitors know it's useful in the same situation.

Comment: oh it show me "A local variable named 'Sander' cannot be declared in the scope because it would give a diffrent meaning to 'sender' which is aleardy used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that. I fixed my code (changed `sender` to `s` in the two worker's lambdas)

Comment: You won't be able to delete a folder within the Program Files directory on Windows Vista, Windows 7, or Windows 8 unless you escalate the program's permissions.  While this code certainly gets the author on the right track, its poorly implemented, and can hardly be considering even passable programming practice.

Comment: @Ramhound That's not what's being asked here, the point is to show OP how to not make his code block the UI thread, thus answering his question "How do I make this not block the UI?"

Comment: @Alex - While it might not have been asked, any modern Windows operating system, will block this from working.  So he is just going to return asking how to do this, so why not implement it the correct way, and call the required code to elevate the permission of the application.

Comment: @Ramhound Feel free to post your own answer, I can't remember the exact code and don't have VS at hand now.